# data persistence to original data source

Tags: intake

Can anybody tell me about below use case is make sense and applicable to intake software component.

We like to use intake to build an abstraction layer or API service endpoint to encapsulate typical data operations, such as data retrieval and data persistence back to original data systems. In short, to build read() and save() from DB system, such as GCP BigQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Intake offers limited writing capabilities (right now): for each data container type, there is only one format supported, for the "persist" (local storage) and "export" (or upload) functions. Your bigquery data is probably dataframe-like, so this would be parquet. I *believe* that you can simply save to GCS, and have bigquery run against these files, but I don't know how you go about it.

There is *not* a general way to write data to any backend which is supported for reading.